# Resolving a private field dependency via DI

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection

I work on an Asp.Net MVC project which defines a custom abstract controller base class from which future controllers should inherit. The controller is defined as following:

```
public abstract class ControllerBase : Controller
{
    private IWorkContextFactory _workContextFactory;
    private WorkContext _workContext;

    public WorkContext WorkContext
    {
        _workContext = _workContext ?? _workContextFactory.BuildContext();
        return _workContext;
    }
}
```

The `WorkContext` class provides useful information such as the id of the logged in user, the user role, etc. The class above as well as the `WorkContext` class are defined in a web framework project which is a class library project. The web framework project is referenced by another project which is the real Asp.Net web project. The Asp.Net web project contains multiple classes to deal with dependency injection such as the resolver (which is an implementation of the `IDependencyResolver` MVC interface and gets set as the dependency resolver at application start with `System.Web.Mvc.DependencyResolver.SetResolver`).

Now I want the `IWorkContextFactory` dependency to be resolved. The only problem is that the web framework project won't reference the web project so I cannot get the instance of the dependency resolver. I also thought about property injection but first I would have to add a reference to the Ninject (which is the DI framework I use) projects in my web framework project to use the `[Inject]` attribute and second I would have to change the visibility of the `IWorkContextFactory` which should be private.

Because I'm running out of ideas to solve this I'm now asking for help.

Comment: It sounds like _web project_ depends on _web framework_, so _web  project_ would be responsible for setting up the dependencies (not the other way around).

Comment: @AndrewS Yes the web project must insert the dependencies into the web framework project. I'm just not sure how to do that because constructor injection isn't suitable as I want types to inherit from the base controller without specifying a special constructor parameter and property injection doesn't seem to be suitable as well

Comment: Why would constructor injection not be suitable when the base class needs it and the extended classes will use it (indirectly)?

Comment: @AndrewS The problem would be that every class that inherits from the ControllerBase class would have to specify a custom constructor taking in a IWorkContextFactory passing it to the base constructor. But since I want it to be a hidden framework detail and I don't want every subclass to be aware of the existence of the IWorkContextFactory interface I thought that maybe there's a preferable solution